# VBA Code to Sort HTML Files into Folder

Tags: html, vba, sorting, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a list of 124 unique HTML files, and a folder containing 1,517 HTML files, including the 124 in the spreadsheet.

Is there a way, via VBA, to find and sort these 124 files into a new folder based on the text in their title? Do the text strings have to be an exact match? Or do I need to code this outside of Excel?

This code is the best I could get so far:

```
Sub Copy_Certain_Files_In_Folder()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileExt As String

FromPath = "C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\to_classify"
ToPath = "C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\to_classify\Ben.Proxy.1"

FileExt = "*.htm*"

If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FromPath = FromPath & "\"
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
    MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

This works well, but I'd like to add a sub that identifies specific htm files listed in the open workbook and **only** moves those specific files. This would be something like `rFileToMatch = wsSource.Range("A2:A125")`, but I'm not sure where to put this within the code. How would I incorporate this element?

Comment: Obviously. You can do this with vba, or with any other languages (which have methods to interact with excel).
If the strings are not an exact match and if you have another solution to match strings, they have not to be an exact match.
Try something in vba (or in any language) if you want some help.

Comment: By Html title which inside html files or by file names?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin by file names

Comment: @ZwoRmi code example added

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
A2 = myfile1.html 
A3 = myfile2.html 
A4 = myfile3.html


Public Sub copyFiles()
    Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sCopyFrom As String, sCopyTo As String
    Dim lFiles As Long, lLastSourceRow As Long
    Dim rFileToMatch As Range
    Dim vbFile As Variant

      On Error Resume Next

      '---------- set up your data here
      sCopyFrom = "C:\CopyFromFolder\"
      sCopyTo = "C:\CopyToFolder\"
      Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
      rFileToMatch = wsSource.Range("A2:A100")        ' range with file names to copy

      For Each vbFile In rFileToMatch
        '---------- no file extension for files to copy!
         MsgBox sCopyFrom & vbFile ' look how look your path to file
        If (Len(Dir(sCopyFrom & vbFile)) > 0) Then

          lFiles = lFiles + 1
          FileCopy sCopyFrom & vbFile, sCopyTo & vbFile
        End If
      Next

      MsgBox lFiles & " files copied.", vbInformation, "Copy Files"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it must by only filenames with extension

Comment: These have the .htm extension, .not .html. This shouldn't affect the macro right?

Comment: [Msgbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fnm4cqgft0po5z/Capture.PNG?dl=0) and [Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zu9zmekzi4mjbfz/Capture2.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: [MsgBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fnm4cqgft0po5z/Capture.PNG?dl=0) and [Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zu9zmekzi4mjbfz/Capture2.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Like I see you never using VBA? do not put strings above Public sub in your code